# Will breakpoints set via SetBreakpoint in JVMTI from one agent be visible to a remote debugger connected to the JVM?

Tags: java, remote-debugging, jvm-hotspot, jvmti, jdwp

Let's assume a remote debugger is connected to the local JVM.
At some point if a JVMTI agent (other than the debugger one) sets a breakpoint via SetBreakpoint, will it be visible to the remote debugger?
Will the remote debugger be able to step over or removee this breakpoint?

By visible I mean that the breakpoint hit event will be sent to the remote debugger, as a result the debugger would be able to behave in the same way as if he was the one that did set the breakpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting breakpoints and receiving Breakpoint events requires [`can_generate_breakpoint_events`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#jvmtiCapabilities.can_generate_breakpoint_events) capability. In HotSpot JVM this capability is exclusive (or [*solo*](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk/file/f3fd73c3a077/src/hotspot/share/prims/jvmtiManageCapabilities.cpp#l146)), i.e. `can_generate_breakpoint_events` may be possessed by only one JVM TI environment at a time.

In other words, the described situation can never happen: when JDWP agent is present, no other JVM TI agent may set breakpoints or subscribe to Breakpoint events.